# UIImageView in Storyboard memory issues - Custom Segues pushViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory, uiimageview, uiimage

I've having some memory issues using ARC in Xcode 5.1.1. I've got several full-screen images in Storyboard in UIImageViews and each time it segues into that View, the image is reloaded and never released resulting in obvious memory problems.

Whats the best way to release those images in the UIImageViews?

This might seem like it could be a duplicate question of other problems, but I think mine is a bit more specific than others I've seen on SO. If you can find an exact duplicate question though, I would love for you to comment that in!

edit: I was using `pushViewController` instead of `popToRootViewController`.

Comment: How do you know that the image is reloaded and never released? (I mean how are you measuring the memory footprint of your app)

Comment: @lucianomarisi Ah, I'm using Instruments to help me track the images and noticing that they do not ever get released automatically.

Comment: I've had "problems" when assessing memory usage while using NSZombieEnabled, have you got that flag on?

Comment: Are you writing your UIImage alloc in viewWillAppear method? Check it and remove it from that and wrote it in viewDidLoad. Also if you provide code that would be helpful for us to clear your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of checking and double checking all my code and researching online, I finally was able to discover my problem. I had accidentally had my custom Segue to infinitely stack on my Navigation Controller by

```
pushViewController
```

instead of

```
popToRootViewController
```

which would be the proper way to automatically release that View.

I thought about deleting this question since it didn't get a final answer, and the solution was so simple, but I decided to answer it myself and maybe someone with a similar problem as me will find this and be reminded to check out their custom Segues!